# How do I access my IBM Cloud BLUEMIX_API_KEY access log

Tags: ibm-cloud

I want to audit my IBM Cloud accesses through specific BLUEMIX_API_KEYs. How do I do that?

Comment: Any more details?

Comment: I would like to see a log of all the accesses (source IPs, time, duration, and api key used) to my account.

Comment: I see Manage->Account->Audit Log which might be the path, but my trial account does not allow this so I can't evaluate if this is sufficient or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [IBM Cloud Activity Tracker service](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/cloud-activity-tracker?topic=cloud-activity-tracker-activity_tracker_ov#activity_tracker_ov) to track security-related events. This is the recommended way of [auditing IAM events](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/iam?topic=iam-tracking#tracking) on IBM Cloud.